# String.Format is not working on dates

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, dataset, string.format

I am executing a sql query and storing it in a dataset, from there i am sending an email, everything works as expected, except for this time attached to the date 12:00:00 Am, it looks really weird on the email, i know that this occurs because the data type of that column is date and the object it gets attached to stores it as datetime and hence gets reset to midnight but i am querying sql directly and retrieving the value from the datatable but it still has the time attached to it. anyways to fix this issue i tried the below but it wont work:

```
string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WorkOrderConnectionString3"].ToString();
SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(conn);
cmd.Connection = sqlconn;
sqlconn.Open();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
String getdatasql = "SELECT WorkOrderNum, Requestor, Date, Department, CompletionDate, MachineDescription, MachineLocation," +
"[Type of Work Order], [Work Required], [WorkPerformed / PartsUsed], [Work Completed By :], [Maint. Supv. Approval]," +
" [Work Comp Date], [Supv Approval Date], Status, [Maint. Supv. Approval Date]" +
"FROM Master WHERE ([Type of Work Order] = N'General') AND (WorkOrderNum = @rockbottom) AND Status = 'Complete' ORDER BY WorkOrderNum DESC";
cmd.CommandText = getdatasql;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rockbottom", TextBox10.Text);
SqlDataAdapter getdata = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
showdata.Fill(ds1);
string WorkOrderNum = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["WorkOrderNum"].ToString();
string Requestor = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Requestor"].ToString();
string Date = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Date"].ToString();
String date = String.Format("{0:MM/d/yyyy}", Date);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When i did an debug i got this:

[image]

In my email it looks like this:

[image]

Tried the Solution still getting the time:

[image]

Got it Working :)

[image]

Comment: @Greg: No, that won't help. Note the type of `Date`.

Comment: @Greg: No, the actual value of `ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Date"]` is likely to be a `DateTime`... but the OP is calling `ToString` on that.

Comment: If you want the `DateTime`-field from the `DataRow` use `DateTime dt = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<DateTime>("Date")`. Don't fiddle around with strings. Then you can use `dt.ToString("MM/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`.

Comment: @Greg: That's the *compile-time* type of `ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Date"]`, but if that were the *execution-time* type, there'd be no information in it. That's why I talked about the "actual value".

Comment: @JonSkeet You're correct, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @JonSkeet your solution didnt work for me i added the result in my question, any alternative??

Comment: @ExpertWannaBe: Your latest screenshot clearly shows that you *didn't* try my solution. Look at my solution carefully - I have changed how you obtain `Date`... you'd then *format* that as normal to obtain `date`. (Again, this wouldn't have been as confusing if you'd chosen better names.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank You Dear Sir :) Next Time More Meaningful names got it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
string Date = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Date"].ToString();
```

Your `Date` variable is already a string, so trying to format that as if it's a `DateTime` isn't going to work. You want something like:

```
DateTime Date = (DateTime) ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Date"];
```

... although I'd recommend against having a local variable named `Date` anyway, especially with a variable called `date` in scope as well...

Comment: off topic, but i noticed you got 800k rep. congrats!